# Prevent - href message in browser

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

When I hover on paging its shows href value in bottom of browser. Can we avoid this?

I know for this we can use different html tag in place of anchor 'a' tag to avoid this.
But is it possible to avoid this with anchor tag.

Problem: its hiding some information bind.

Comment: @str actually its hiding some information bind.

Comment: You can omit the `href` attribute altogether, However, adding proper links like `href="#page/3"` would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<a href="link.html" title="Titletext"><span title=" ">text</span></a>
```